# How to save data in database safe in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, security, laravel-5, sanitization

I won't have a  Comment Form that anybody can fill it, and the input data will be inserted in the database after a validation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\comments;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CommentController  extends Controller
{
    public function postCommentNew( Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'commenter' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|max:255',
            'comment' => 'required',
            'post_id' => 'required'
        ]);
        comments::create( $request->all() );

        return redirect()->back()->with('success' , 'Comment Submited') ;
    }


}
```

now I want to be sure that nobody will not damage my site! I want to save data completely safe! I don't know if is it necessary to sanitize form input. if your answer is yes, How should I do it?

I have seen this [here](http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/03/31/sanitizing-input-using-laravel-5-form-requests/) :

```
public function sanitize()
    {
        $input = $this->all();

        if (preg_match("#https?://#", $input['url']) === 0) {
            $input['url'] = 'http://'.$input['url'];
        }

        $input['name'] = filter_var($input['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $input['description'] = filter_var($input['description'], 
        FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $this->replace($input);     
    }
```

Comment: I am asking about a sanitizing filter just for database insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to [Laravel 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) documentation:

> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through
> PHP's `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS attacks.

So the answer is You do not need to build extra things to sanitize form input.

Regarding SQL injection, Laravel uses PDO-prepared statements ([Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)) and it is protected against possible SQL injection.

The example in your question is intended to protect injection from URLs, which is fine.

And finally, I have mentioned this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329501/about-laravel-5-1-security/33329688#33329688) to you previously.

It is not enough to count on documentation and my answer. Therefore, I would like to highlight this from the above link again:

> You need to do your penetration test when your project is done to
> Ensure everything is working and secured as planned